# createBottomTabNavigator has moved to error message

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I am getting an error message on Expo which says ''createBottomTabNavigator()' has been moved to 'react-navigation-tabs'. See http........ for more details

I have done npm install react-navigation-tabs and changed my imports but those changes did not get rid of the error

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'

import HomeScreen from './Home';

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen,
    SignUp: SignUpScreen
},
);

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

I expected that after installing react-navigation-tabs and changing my imports, the problem would be fixed.

Comment: rebuilding and restarting the metro bundler may help you.

Comment: I had the same issue, I deleted the `node_modules` and ran `yarn` then started the project and it worked fine.

Comment: Nothing is wrong in your code. Try running re-run your app

Comment: Try `expo start -c`

Answer (score 0):

That because react-navigation version 4, all navigators have been moved to separate repos so you have to install them separately.

```
npm i react-navigation-stack   // or yarn add react-navigation-stack
```

after that, go to the file where you define createStackNavigator and change:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
```

to:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `createBottomTabNavigator` inside `createAppContainer` which will be imported from `react-navigation`.

```
import {  createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

const TabNavigator = createAppContainer(createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  SignUp: SignUpScreen
},
));

export default TabNavigator;
```

`